# Controller not receiving the uploaded file from POSTMAN

Tags: java, spring, multipartform-data, multipart

I am creating the REST controller in Spring(Not Spring boot),where i am trying to receive a file through postman but am getting the following exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.multipart.AttachmentUtils.getAttachments(AttachmentUtils.java:120)
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.MultipartProvider.readFrom(MultipartProvider.java:147)
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBodyReader(JAXRSUtils.java:1280)
```

My controller looks like below:

```
@POST
@Path("/uploadMyFile")
@Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile file);
```

The same code I was able to get the file in spring boot.

Comment: what is the package of Multipart?

Comment: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

Comment: why is this package handling the error?
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.multipart
Can you post your whole code?

Answer (score 0):

the controller looks ok.
The import for the multipart should be having the following line of code.

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
```

Please verify this.

If It is okay that you need to provide other details, There might be some logically error in implementation.

Comment: yea..Using the same import.In the implementation part am just printing the log